# How to update package cache when using module package from ansible

Tags: ansible, package-managers

If I run apt, I can update the package cache:

```
apt:
  name: postgresql
  state: present
  update_cache: yes
```

I'm now trying to use the generic `package` command, but I don't see a way to do this.

```
package:
  name: postgresql
  state: present
```

Do I have to run an explicit command to run `apt-get update`, or can I do this using the package module?

Comment: What is the problem to solve?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. I'm trying to install a package. On ubuntu, in my particular environment, I have to call apt-get update first, or it fails. I'd like to use `package` to minimize the distro specific commands I use.

Comment: If you want to use `package` then fork it and patch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not possible.

The module `package` as of writing is just capable to handle package presence, so you have to use directly the package module to refresh the cache.

Comment: ok, but can you provide an example playbook that *does* meet OP's needs? Maybe one where the first task uses the `apt` module to update the cache (using `when` so it only executes on apt-based systems), then uses the `package` module to install?

Answer (score 7):

You can't with the package module, unfortunately, but you can do a two-step where you update the cache first before running the rest of your playbook(s).

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Update Package Cache (apt/Ubuntu)
    tags: always
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
    changed_when: false
    when: ansible_distribution == "Ubuntu"

  - name: Update Package Cache (dnf/CentOS)
    tags: always
    dnf:
      update_cache: yes
    changed_when: false
    when: ansible_distribution == "CentOS"

  - name: Update Package Cache (yum/Amazon)
    tags: always
    yum:
      update_cache: yes
    changed_when: false
    when: ansible_distribution == "Amazon"
```

Comment: why is changed_when set to false? I guess it's difficult to determine if that really changed something, but wouldn't `true` for could always have changed something be better as default? Where is the advantage in false?

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

Nowadays, Ansible provides a generic solution :

```
- name: Update package cache
  ansible.builtin.package:
    update_cache: true
```

---

Unfortunately, Ansible does not yet offer a generic solution.

However, the variable `ansible_pkg_mgr` provides reliable information about the installed package manager. In turn, you can use this information to call the specific Ansible package modules. Please find attached an example for all common package managers.

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: update apt cache
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        update_cache: yes
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == "apt"
    
    - name: update yum cache
      ansible.builtin.yum:
        update_cache: yes
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == "yum"
    
    - name: update apk cache
      community.general.apk:
        update_cache: yes
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == "apk"
    
    - name: update dnf cache
      ansible.builtin.dnf:
        update_cache: yes
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == "dnf"
    
    - name: update zypper cache
      community.general.zypper:
        name: zypper
        update_cache: yes
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == "zypper"
    
    - name: update pacman cache
      community.general.pacman:
        update_cache: yes
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == "pacman"
```

Comment: Note the `become: yes` for all tasks if copying only single blocks!

Answer (score 4):

## Yes.

Simply include `update_cache: yes` in your call to the `ansible.builtin.package` module:

```yaml
package:
  name: postgresql
  state: present
  update_cache: yes
```

This works because [as of 2020](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/3af7425367db1ab77e3d684ab8cf849bc68381a2), Ansible passes any additional arguments to the underlying package manager:

> While all arguments will be passed to the underlying module, not all modules support the same arguments. This documentation only covers the minimum intersection of module arguments that all packaging modules support.

Source: [Package Module Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I read in official and latest Doc from Ansible, and nothing regarding update_cache appears to be documented there:

[ansible_doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html)

But testing at home, I made ansible fail, in order to read the failure, and update_cache seems to be one of the options to use:

[image: update_cache]

Comment: It seems to pass the option to pacman module, so I think any option that works with your package module sould work as well